# Is there no way to switch to Ubuntu dual boot from within Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I use both Windows and Ubuntu frequently, the former for things like gaming while the latter is more for programming, but it's somewhat of an (albeit small) hassle to have to restart and then select which drive I want to boot into.

I was wondering if there is no way to log into Ubuntu directly from Windows, and vice versa (essentially bypassing me having to select which boot drive I want to use)?

I have tried using VMs for convenience, and as long as I limit my usage to the terminal and maybe a browser it works decently, but as soon as I open up an IDE the speed becomes a big issue.

Lastly, if it is the case that no such (non-VM) solution exists, is this because operating systems are isolated from the BIOS and don't have that low-level control over BIOS boot processes? Not yet in college so don't really know yet about the workings of operating systems but hope to learn more soon. Thanks!

Comment: Any dual-boot implies rebooting whenever you need to boot the other OS. It was always like that and always will be. That said, a proper Windows-Ubuntu dual-boot does NOT imply anything firmware (BIOS or UEFI) related, only a selection from the Grub menu. If you need to change settings it's likely because you have the OSes installed in different modes.

Comment: Hardware hypervisor lets you boot both at the same time and switch with a keyboard shortcut. Software hypervisor like virtualbox or vmware does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental difference to be understood is the difference between a physical machine and a virtual machine. To prevent conflicts in a physical machine more than one operating system cannot have control of the same hardware at the same time.

This diagram shows how control in a physical machine passes from the firmware (BIOS or UEFI) to the bootloader and from the bootloader to the operating system in Ubuntu.

[image]
          <sup>**BIOS vs. UEFI**</sup>

There are several ways to bypass this flow of control by running Ubuntu inside of Windows instead of *alongside* Windows (*as is done in a single or dual boot*). In all of these ways the Ubuntu instance shares the hardware resources of the computer with Windows when Ubuntu is running.

1. Run Ubuntu as a guest OS in a virtual machine application.
2. WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), was introduced in Windows 10 (64-bit). It provides a Linux-compatible kernel interface written by Microsoft with no Linux code, so that a user-mode Ubuntu image can run natively on top, rather than in a container or virtual machine. This allows for resource-efficient access to bash shells and other Ubuntu programs within a Windows OS.
3. Docker provides the ability to package and run an application in a loosely isolated environment called a container. The isolation and security allow you to run many containers simultaneously on a given host. Containers are lightweight and contain everything needed to run the application, so you do not need to rely on what is currently installed on the host.  <sup>[source](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is an OS not an app so no there is no way to run Ubuntu as an OS from inside windows.

Bottom line you must reboot if you do not want to use a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Google "Windows System for Linux". It is Microsoft's accommodation for Linux users. Once installed you can install Ubuntu in WSL.